# Clear apache server memory cache

Tags: apache, caching

I'm using mod_mem_cache in my apache web server to cache static content, but I need to know how to clear the cache.  For disk cache I guess you can just erase the directory or use htcacheclean?  But I'm not sure what to do for memory cache (without restarting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using an external cache server (like Memcached) with Apache's `mod_memcache_cache`. [Guide here](http://www.mabishu.com/blog/2009/12/08/using-memcache-server-as-apache-content-cach/).

You have very easy access to it from anywhere and it makes dumping the contents into the Gulf when you don't want them anymore very simple.